# Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException Missing required parameter for [Route: admin.doctor.edit] [Missing parameter: doctor]

Tags: php, laravel-8

I haven't touch my code for 2 weeks, and I don't know what happened today, as I got this error on .edit route

Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameter for [Route: admin.doctor.edit] [URI: admin/doctor/{doctor}/edit] [Missing parameter: doctor].

Example of error

http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/doctor/28

http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/user/3

Please find the complete code below

[Complete code](https://github.com/ivanwilliammd/emr-clinic/)

Comment: Additional hint: after I delete the validator class, it seems to be working normally?

Answer (score 0):

The link you attached is broken,

however it looks like your wanting a 'doctor id' not a `{doctor}`